# Verification DATE in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have small question.

How can I do this: A client adds a DATA to a FORMS
[image]

I want to check in MYSQL if the existing DATA is set by another client.

So, in this picture you can see how I don't want to be

[image]
I want to return something MESSAGE to say to client *Please change another DATE*.

Comment: 1st: Make your date column unique/id, so mysql itself prevents it from inserting. (This will throw an error on php side if you try to insert the same date). 2nd: Before insert you have to check if date already exists or you catch the exception.

Comment: Please add some code... Are you using a framework, or is it custom structure ? What's the structure of your mysql table ?

Comment: Voted to close this question for more details and clarity. @BogdamM tagged this question with PHP and MySQL. Since this seems to be completely wrong it is not clear, what exactly is expacted or what exactly is ment.

Answer (score 0):

When it belongs to dates, use the date and time functions of php and mysql.

First of all use a `DATE` type column for storing dates in your database. A short example, how to declare a `DATE` column. This example contains the `UNIQUE` constraint for date `DATE` column, so that a value can be stored only once in this column.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);
```

Keep in mind, that this is an example table. Now you can do all the things you are asking for based in this `DATE` column.

Now you have to deal with your date format on PHP side. I guess the calendar app posts the date format as shown as `d/m/Y`. This kind of format is acceptable, but not ususal for dealing with dates wether in your database nor in your php code. Mostly the format `Y-m-d` is used. This format fits the needs of your database.

The following example takes a post parameter for your calendar date in the format `d\m\Y` and creates a php `DateTime` object out of it.

```
$data = $_POST['date']; // your date in d/m/Y format like 20/05/2021
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y');

if ($date === false) {
    throw new Exception('The given date is not in the expected format d/mY.');
}

// create the desired format for the database
$value = $date->format('Y-m-d');

// check for this date in your database
$sql = "SELECT id FROM example WHERE start_date = :start_date";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':start_date', $value);
$statement->execute();

// fetch a possible result
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// ongoing further processing
var_dump($row);
```

The example above uses `PDO` for fetching data out of your mysql database. Whatever database adapter you use, the procedure stays the same. Declare a unique `DATE` column in your database table, use the data time functions and classes and check for an existing date in your database.

PS: You don 't have to pre-selected from your database. Another way could be fetching an error on trying to insert a dataset with an already existing date value. Based on the unique constraint in your database table for the date column, your insert results into an error. You can avoid this behaviour by using something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` sql queries or catching the error on an insert statement with a try/catch block around your database adapter, if it throws exceptions in such cases.

Comment: "Doesn 't work for me" is the same category like "There is an error". Completely without any information to help you. It would be kind of good if you could express yourself in a little more detail. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: My PHP version dosen't like *DateTime::CreateFormFormat('d/m/Y')* .

Comment: There was a typo in the code. You shouldn 't just copy code. Try to understand, what 's going on. The DateTime class is available since PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an ajax call when the client selects a date and check if that exists in the table just reset the date value and toast to the client for selecting another date. Along with this, you may also disable the form submit button when the date value is empty so to prevent accidental duplication.

On  Mysql side set date column unique and when throwing a message catch it in response and show a toast as @DefinitelynotRafal commented above.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the current date by using `date(d-m-Y)` (d-m-y means day-month-year format) and then compare it to the data's date in the database if it has been set by another client

Comment: Suggested format is not suitable in MySQL.